# Node.js Visual Studio 2015 getting the breakpoint will not currently be hit no code has been loaded

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015

Using the new VisualStudio 2015 node.js tools i:
1. created new empty node.js project
2. added the directory's which contains the project files.
then i run the application from visual studio where app.js is the entry point . 
the app is working fine from VS .
but when i want to debug the app , i can only set break-point at app.js 
when i tiring to set break point in one of the files i added
it gives me this massage :

> the breakpoint will not currently be hit no code has been loaded

im using :

```
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA582 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
> Node.js Tools   1.1.30910.02 Adds support for developing and debugging
> Node.js apps in Visual Studio
> 
> Node.js Tools - Profiling   1.1.30910.02 Profiling support for Node.js
> projects.
```